# Cordova - Barcode Scanner

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I need some help with a plugin I found on github.
https://github.com/Dbuggerx/BarcodeScanner

Is it possible to change the text at the bottom of the screen and the text that comes up on success ?

There's no proper documentation to use this plugin, I tried searching for some kind of documentation to use this plugin but I couldn't find any. Maybe someone on here has used it and knows how it works ?

Comment: I managed to change the bottom label text when scanning a barcode, I just need to figure out if there's a way to change the success label text that pops up after scan.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what this message is?  I'm looking in the plugin source code, but don't know what string you are looking for.  I would guess it's either in the plugin source or the underlying zxing scanner library that it uses.

Comment: Hi Simon,

So it seems that one of the contributors has fixed this on the official github page https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner but the build seems to be failing.

Can I ask you, how do you edit these files to make changes ? I'd love to know how to so I can do this myself, but I'm a newbie to all of this :)